# Build line through points with variances in both coordinates

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have some points, and both of each point's coordinates have variances. It is stored in arrays (just an example):

```
x  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dx <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
dy <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

and each point's coordinates are (x +/- dx, y +/- dy).

I want to fit it with line y=k*x and get result: k +/- dk.

Comment: Are the dx and dy values constant like in your example? Are the distributions around x and y symmetrical? Normal?

Answer (score 3):

Terry Therneau answered this on rhelp earlier this year, citing a 1987 paper by Prof. Ripley:
Besides "total least squares" it is also call Deming regression and orthogonal regression:

[Rhelp text at Baron's R Search page](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2010-February/227865.html)

```
# Generalized Deming regression, based on Ripley, Analyst, 1987:377-383.
#
deming <- function(x, y, xstd, ystd, jackknife=TRUE, dfbeta=FALSE,
                   scale=TRUE) {
    Call <- match.call()
    n <- length(x)
    if (length(y) !=n) stop("x and y must be the same length")
    if (length(xstd) != length(ystd)) 
        stop("xstd and ystd must be the same length") 

    # Do missing value processing
    nafun <- get(options()$na.action)
    if (length(xstd)==n) {
        tdata <- nafun(data.frame(x=x, y=y, xstd=xstd, ystd=ystd))
        x <- tdata$x
        y <- tdata$y
        xstd <- tdata$xstd
        ystd <- tdata$ystd
        }
    else {
        tdata <- nafun(data.frame(x=x, y=y))
        x <- tdata$x
        y <- tdata$y
        if (length(xstd) !=2) stop("Wrong length for std specification")
        xstd <- xstd[1] + xstd[2]*x
        ystd <- ystd[1] + ystd[2] * y
        }

    if (any(xstd <=0) || any(ystd <=0)) stop("Std must be positive")

    minfun <- function(beta, x, y, xv, yv) {
        w <- 1/(yv + beta^2*xv)
        alphahat <- sum(w * (y - beta*x))/ sum(w)
        sum(w*(y-(alphahat + beta*x))^2)
        }

    minfun0 <- function(beta, x, y, xv, yv) {
        w <- 1/(yv + beta^2*xv)
        alphahat <- 0  #constrain to zero
        sum(w*(y-(alphahat + beta*x))^2)
        }

    afun <-function(beta, x, y, xv, yv) {
        w <- 1/(yv + beta^2*xv)
        sum(w * (y - beta*x))/ sum(w)
        }

    fit <- optimize(minfun, c(.1, 10), x=x, y=y, xv=xstd^2, yv=ystd^2)
    coef = c(intercept=afun(fit$minimum, x, y, xstd^2, ystd^2), 
               slope=fit$minimum)
    fit0 <- optimize(minfun0, coef[2]*c(.5, 1.5), x=x, y=y, 
                     xv=xstd^2, yv=ystd^2)

    w <- 1/(ystd^2 + (coef[2]*xstd)^2) #weights
    u <- w*(ystd^2*x + xstd^2*coef[2]*(y-coef[1])) #imputed "true" value
    if (is.logical(scale) && scale) {
        err1 <- (x-u)/ xstd
        err2 <- (y - (coef[1] + coef[2]*u))/ystd
        sigma <- sum(err1^2 + err2^2)/(n-2)
        # Ripley's paper has err = [y - (a + b*x)] * sqrt(w); gives the same SS
        }
    else sigma <- scale^2

    test1 <- (coef[2] -1)*sqrt(sum(w *(x-u)^2)/sigma) #test for beta=1
    test2 <- coef[1]*sqrt(sum(w*x^2)/sum(w*(x-u)^2) /sigma) #test for a=0

    rlist <- list(coefficient=coef, test1=test1, test0=test2, scale=sigma,
                  err1=err1, err2=err2, u=u)

    if (jackknife) {
        delta <- matrix(0., nrow=n, ncol=2)
        for (i in 1:n) {
            fit <- optimize(minfun, c(.5, 1.5)*coef[2], 
                            x=x[-i], y=y[-i], xv=xstd[-i]^2, yv=ystd[-i]^2)
            ahat <- afun(fit$minimum, x[-i], y[-i], xstd[-i]^2, ystd[-i]^2)
            delta[i,] <- coef - c(ahat, fit$minimum)
            }
        rlist$variance <- t(delta) %*% delta
        if (dfbeta) rlist$dfbeta <- delta
        }

    rlist$call <- Call
    class(rlist) <- 'deming'
    rlist
    }

print.deming <- function(x, ...) {
    cat("\nCall:\n", deparse(x$call), "\n\n", sep = "")
    if (is.null(x$variance)) {
        table <- matrix(0., nrow=2, ncol=3)
        table[,1] <- x$coefficient
        table[,2] <- c(x$test0, x$test1)
        table[,3] <- pnorm(-2*abs(table[,2]))
        dimnames(table) <- list(c("Intercept", "Slope"),
                                c("Coef", "z", "p"))
        }
    else {
        table <- matrix(0., nrow=2, ncol=4)
        table[,1] <- x$coefficient
        table[,2] <- sqrt(diag(x$variance))
        table[,3] <- c(x$test0, x$test1)
        table[,4] <- pnorm(-2*abs(table[,3]))
        dimnames(table) <- list(c("Intercept", "Slope"),
                                c("Coef", "se(coef)", "z", "p"))
        }
    print(table, ...)
    cat("\n   Scale=", format(x$scale, ...), "\n")
    invisible(x)
    }
```

Comment: Deming regression is a special case of total least squares (TLS) where there are two variables and independent errors - as per the Eol's Q. TLS is a more general model for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to perform a *total least squares* fit. There's a whole book on this, "The total least squares problem: computational aspects and analysis", by Sabine van Huffel, Joos Vandewalle. [Wikpedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) should provide enough for you to code up a solution - it's basically "take the SVD of a slightly augmented system"